# How to introduce time parameter in an equation?

Tags: derivatives, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I was working for my project. And in my project I need to use conditional probability. Actually I need to find probability of an event A, given that event B already occurred **ahead of time**

Say A is an event which is electricity blackout and B is an event which is high heatwaves. Now, I want to find out P(electricity = blackout | heatwave = high). I can find probability by using Bayes' theorem. But, If I want to find probability ahead of some 'X' time. Then what should I suppose to do?

I have little knowledge on math tools. Like I was thinking does derivative do anything here to bring time in account? How actually researchers say somethings like probability of rising global temperature within **5 years** given that if we cut down forest by x%?

I also got confused on what different context do I need to use conditional probability and bayes' theorem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession

Comment: Your question is vague. What are events A and B? "Introducing time parameter" is also hard to understand. Can you add some more details please?

Comment: @K.defaoite I tried to make my question little bit precise. Could you please read again?

Comment: So you want to find the probability there is a blackout given we had a heatwave some number of years ago?

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes